# Symfony security users without any role

Tags: symfony, security, roles

I was looking at the [symfony security dynamic roles instructions](https://knpuniversity.com/screencast/symfony-security/dynamic-roles) at knplabs page. It says "Second, there's just one rule that we need to follow about roles: every user must have at least one role. Otherwise, weird stuff happens."

Does anybody know exactly what happens to users which has no role? I assumed they would just be able to access pages which require such rights. But the text makes it sound like something terribly strange happens?

Answer (score 0):

I got response from KnpLabs:

> Well... there is some weird stuff :). Internally, even after you
>   login, you will appear as "unauthenticated" in the web debug toolbar,
>   and some other parts of your system might thing that you are also not
>   logged in. The issue is that, internally, in a few places, Symfony
>   decides whether or not you are authenticated by counting the roles on
>   the user. If the user has 0, the user appears "unauthenticated". Parts
>   of your system might work fine, but other parts might behave "weird"
>   :)